# Time remap doesn't interpolate cloth simulation properly

Tags: rendering, animation, modifiers, cloth-simulation, timeline

I animated my scene before realising I wanted it at a higher framerate. Oops! Rookie mistake.

So I enabled time remapping and stretched it out to twice the duration (from 100 frames to 200 frames). Everything interpolated smoothly, **except** for my cloth simulation. That made sense since I baked it before time remapping, and I could see it only generated 100 .bphys frames to disk.

So I deleted my bake, set the simulation speed to half, and baked it again. I could see it generated 200 .bphys files this time, so I thought it was fixed. But when I scrubbed through the timeline frame-by-frame, I could see that it was just repeating the same frames twice (instead of properly interpolating the in-between motion). So while everything else was running at 50fps, my cloth simulation still **appeared to be** going at 25fps.

I've decided to just stretch the keyframes out on my dopesheet instead of using time remapping for the time being, but I just wanted to know if anybody else has encountered this and can offer a solution? It would save me a lot of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So ... if I'm right, cloth sim doesn't have subframes (substeps) and I don't see any interpolation to solve those jumps (smooth missing transitions).

As a workaround you can try export the cloth sim object as *Alembic* (.abc) format without time-remapping. Under *Output Properties > Dimension > Time Remapping* set *New* > 200. Import this object back and under *Modifiers Properties* you can find already added **Mesh Sequence Cache** modifier > enable **Vertex Interpolation**. It will generate smooth transition between ramped time frames.

[image]

Comment: Massive thanks! I'm still new to Blender so I never knew about this modifier. This will help me out in the future.

Comment: If answer solved your issue consider mark answer as accepted so other can see it from main list and system is not pocking Q in period. Thank you keep site organised. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour